# App is not launching when i start appium server

Tags: android, appium

I writen a code to launch one app

Code is written in eclipse and using Appium server i m launching it.

The same code is executing if i run in other mobile models.

Only in my mobile, it gives the below exception and app is not launching at all

Mobile : Redmi Note 4

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An
>   unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Cannot stop and clear com.testleaf.leaforg. Original
>   error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s c219ce599904
>   shell pm clear com.testleaf.leaforg' exited with code 1'; Stderr:
>   'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: PID 28662 does not have
>   permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear data of
>   package com.testleaf.leaforg'; Code: '1' (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information)

In Appium server, the below errors are getting printed

> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot
>   stop and clear com.testleaf.leaforg. Original error: Error executing
>   adbExec. Original error: 'Command
>   'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s c219ce599904
>   shell pm clear com.testleaf.leaforg' exited with code 1'; Stderr:
>   'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: PID 28662 does not have
>   permission android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA to clear data of
>   package com.testleaf.leaforg'; Code: '1'
>       at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (C:\Users\Nyla jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-support\lib\logging.js:63:13)
>       at ADB.callee$0$0$ (C:\Users\Nyla jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\tools\adb-commands.js:196:9)
>       at tryCatch (C:\Users\Nyla jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\Nyla jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (C:\Users\Nyla
>   jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (C:\Users\Nyla jannath\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet?

Comment: Don't just write exception without mentioning what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall “unlock” Appium app to avoid above Error.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem Raised to me please make sure **appium settings** app installed.
Try with kill server command: **adb kill-server**
& Need to start it again command: **adb start-server**